# React Native Layout - Flexbox with responsive images

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flexbox, responsive, responsive-images

I'd like to achieve a layout with Flexbox in React Native. The idea is to be able to have a responsive image with text beneath it, vertically centered in on the page.

The issue seems that the View that contains the image, either ends up disappearing as the image has no height or filling the entire screen height and pushing the text that shoud be below the image down to the bottom.

I assume its to do with the image dimensions being undefined in order to get it to act in a responsive way and fill the parent container.

[Here's a mockup of the layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xup0.png)

### Update

Thanks Topik Mujianto - I was actually following that very tutorial!

Here's my code:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  pageContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection:'row', 
    justifyContent:'center',
    backgroundColor: "blue",
    alignItems: 'flex-start'
  },
  columnStyle: {
    flex: 0.7,
    flexDirection:'column', 
    backgroundColor: "red",
    borderWidth: 1,
    alignItems: 'flex-start'
  },

  imgStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    height: undefined,
    width: undefined,
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
  }
})

const Component = props => (
  <View style={styles.pageContainer}>
    <View style={styles.columnStyle}>
      <Image 
      style={styles.imgStyle}
      resizeMode="contain" 
      source={require('../../../assets/images/onboarding-how-it-works.png')}
      />
    </View>
  </View>
);
```

Which gives this:

[Centered on page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDOwl.png)

But if I try to get the image to align top with this code:

```
  imgStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    height: undefined,
    width: undefined,
    alignSelf: 'felx-start',
  }
```

I get this (the image has disappeared):

[No image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdVgs.png)

After a bit more investigation I can see that acutally the image is stretching to fit as it has the flex: 1 property. I set the background colour to yellow on the image and get this:

[Image background shows size of image box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PVzB.png)

So the question is, how do I get the image to be responsive without its container stretching to the parent and shrinking to fit the responsive image content, and then align it to the top?